# Maintaining Temperature in wine production

Tags: fermentation, wine, temperature

In wine production is maintaining a 20 degree C temperature a critical factor after first fermentation?

Answer (score 1):

After primary fermentation maintaining 20C is not critical, you would probably want to store it a bit cooler, I always do my secondary conditioning in the cellar at about 12C.

During primary fermentation temperature control will affect the esters and higher alcohol production from the yeast. After the first 5 days this become less important, but will still have a small affect.